# How to get swf on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I created a facebook app and the login loads but once it does that I get a blank screen.  Its seems like my swf is not loading at all.  This is my index.php file:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <!-- Include support librarys first -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var APP_ID = "my_id";
      var REDIRECT_URI = "my_url";
      var PERMS = "publish_stream, user_photos"; //comma separated list of extended permissions

      function init()
      {
        FB.init({appId:APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true});
        FB.getLoginStatus(handleLoginStatus);
      }

      function handleLoginStatus(response)
      {
        if (response.session) { //Show the SWF

          swfobject.embedSWF("main.swf", "flashContent", "640", "480", "9.0", null, null, null, {name:"flashContent"});

        } else { //ask the user to login

          var params = window.location.toString().slice(window.location.toString().indexOf('?'));
          top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='+APP_ID+'&scope='+PERMS+'&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URI + params;
        }
      }
      $(init);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="ConnectDemo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any reason why this wouldnt work?

Comment: and your app link? (So that we can check via firebug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the `swfobject.embedSWF` needs to be the `id` of the element to which you are injecting the SWF.  You use `flashContent` which doesn't exist in your DOM?

Comment: If this does turn out to be the answer, then this debugging step should have been done way before posting to StackOverflow.  SO should be used as a last resort *after* you've exhausted your other options.